# Как настроить jsp в spring mvc & tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{MyWebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { MyWebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
}
```

//

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "ru" })
public class MyWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        resolver.setExposePathVariables(true);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

//

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView test(){
        return new ModelAndView("index", "name", "Word");
    }
}
```

//

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello <c:out value="${name}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

//

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      <version>10.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**вместо Hello Word**

выводит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

`<c:out value="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'"/>`

Comment: не помогло, 'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'

Answer (score 0):

Может легче будет использовать спринг вместо j2ee

https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyZFK4LBjj0&ab_channel=%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C

Comment: там все встроено - томкат, сервлеты

Comment: мне нужно без spring boot